# Can, could, will and would usage and difference

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I see countless of people using "can", "could", "will" and "would", simply using them, mixing them up and more. I am not sure and want to be clear of the meaning, usage and difference of these words.

These are a few examples:

Can and could

a) I can check your order and see how is the status.
b) I could check your oder and see how is the status.
a2) Can you give me a lift back home?
b2) Could you give me a lift back home?

Will and would
a) I will help you with your homework tomorrow.
b) I would help you with your homework tomorrow.
a2) Will you refund my money?
b2) Would you refund my money?

Comment: Please see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would) on the ELU site and many other previous questions, such as some of those linked in the panel on the right.

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference which of ***can/could*** you use in the first case (unless you're sarcastically saying *Even though I **could** do it, **I won't***). You'd only usually say *I **would** help...* if you were going to continue by specifying the *preconditions* under which you would help *(otherwise, you **won't**)*. Asking someone if they ***would*** do something is just a bit more "deferential, polite" than asking if they ***will*** do it, but basically they mean the same.